# Chaining swift combine publishers and receiving each result

Tags: swift, combine

In the example below, I’m making a network request to load different movie genres, then using that to load all the movies. The sink only returns the movie results. How could I receive both the genres and movies?

```
struct Genre: Codable, Identifiable{
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    var movies: [Movie]?
}

struct Movie: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    let title: String
    let id: Int
    let posterPath: String?
    let backdropPath : String?
    var tagline: String?
}

loadGenres() is AnyPublisher<[Genre], Error> 
fetchMoviesIn() is AnyPublisher<[Movie], Error>

class GenresViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var genres = [Genre]()
    @Published var movies = [Movie]()
    var requests = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init(){
        NetworkManager.shared.loadGenres()
            .flatMap{ genres in
                genres.publisher.flatMap{ genre in
                    NetworkManager.shared.fetchMoviesIn(genre)
                }
            }
            .collect()
            .retry(1)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                switch completion{
                case .finished:
                    print("Finished loading all movies in every genre")
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
            }, receiveValue: { [self] values in
                let allMovies = values.joined()
                self.movies = allMovies.map{$0}
            })
            .store(in: &self.requests)
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the return types of your `loadGenres()` and `fetchMoviesIn` methods?

Comment: AnyPublisher<[Genre], Error> and AnyPublisher<[Movie], Error>

Comment: @RichardWitherspoon, how do you want to collect the final results? For example: `[(Genre, [Movie])]` is an array of genre-to-movies mappings, or just independent arrays: `([Genre], [Movie])`

Comment: @NewDev preferable the first, but if you could provide examples for both so I understand the difference that would be amazing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends on how you want to collect genres and movies.

For example, do you want a genre and a list of movies in that genre? The result could be an array of `(Genre, [Movies])`.

```
NetworkManager.shared.loadGenres()
   .flatMap { genres in
       genres.publisher.setFailureType(to: Error.self)
   }
   .flatMap { genre in
       NetworkManager.shared.fetchMoviesIn(genre)
          .map { movies in (genre, movies) } 
   }
   .collect()
```

Or, if you want an array of `(Genre, Movie)` tuples, then it's a similar approach, but with an additional level of `.flatMap` to get individual movies

```
NetworkManager.shared.loadGenres()
   .flatMap { genres in
       genres.publisher.setFailureType(to: Error.self)
   }
   .flatMap { genre in
       NetworkManager.shared.fetchMoviesIn(genre)
          .flatMap { movies in
              movies.publisher.setFailureType(to: Error.self)
          }
          .map { movie in (genre, movie) }
   }
   .collect()
```

---

To answer your comment question, you want to return the updated `Genre`, you could return that instead of returning a tuple. Bear in mind that since `Genre` is a struct, you'd need to create a variable copy of the object (the `genre` available in the `flatMap` closure is a constant), update the copy, and return that:

```
NetworkManager.shared.loadGenres()
   .flatMap { genres in
       genres.publisher.setFailureType(to: Error.self)
   }
   .flatMap { genre in
       NetworkManager.shared.fetchMoviesIn(genre)
          .map { movies -> Genre in
             var genreCopy = genre
             genreCopy.movies = movies
             return genreCopy
          }
   }
   .collect()
```

Comment: What a great answer! This is perfect. For my use case the first approach is the best. Also Genre has a  movies property ([Movie]?) . How would I take the values that are returned in the completion and stuff them into the published property of the class?

Comment: I added my solution to your answer, but I feel like there's still a better way to do it.

Comment: @RichardWitherspoon, thanks for the edit, but I don't think it should be in the answer, since it muddies the water a bit more more concepts. Again... all depends on what you want the publisher chain to return to a subscriber. If you tuples are ok, then you can handle them in `.sink`. If you want the subscribers to receive the "completed" `Genre` objects, then instead of create a tuple, create a copy / update the genre object with the `movies` property, and return that.

Comment: I removed my edit. Any chance you can update it with your explanation? Sorry Combine is still mind bending for me.

Comment: So, instead of doing `.map { movies in (genre, movies) }`, you can do: `.map { movies in genre.movies = movies; return genre }`, if `Genre` has a property `.movies`. Or, you can do what you suggest in the edit - it's up to you and depends on how you want to factor your code.

Comment: Doing that results in "Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate"

Comment: @RichardWitherspoon, is `Genre` a struct or a class? Can you edit your question with how `Genre` is defined, and I'll update my answer

Comment: Thank you so so much! This has been extremely helpful. I'm going to reference this post so many times going forward.

Comment: I've been scouring the internet for hours, and this was literally the last link I was going to come to, and I can't believe the solution was so simple. ‍♂️